# lrmate200ic automode

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-hydro, ros-industrial, fanuc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please, help me,

I work with fanuc lrmate200ic (V7.7 with R648 and R632) and ROS Hydro. I have done basic configuration. I began to test steering of an indstrial robot but the robot executes commands only under the T1 mode. When I switch the robot in auto mode and run a `ros` TPE program i see only

```
I RREL Waiting for ROS traj relay
```

message and when i run command

```
roslaunch fanuc_lrmate200ic_moveit_config moveit_planning_execution.launch sim:=false robot_ip:=IP_OF_ROBOT
```

on PC, TP displays message `Connected`. But, further communication is not possible.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226452/lrmate200ic-automode/) by [alex_wwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/25926/alex_wwa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-02-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-12**:
Running the `fanuc_driver` Karel & TP programs in AUTO mode is definitely possible. Can you check the robot's *error log*, and please update your question (use the *edit* button/link) with the exact steps you take to start the `ros` TPE program (ie: programs selected, buttons pressed, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you very much, you were right, error was in the process. It was necessary to enter into the ros  TPE program and after that press cycle start on control panel. Thanks for your time.

---

Originally posted by [alex_wwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/25926/alex_wwa/) with karma: 16 on 2016-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0